# Still having "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large"

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I have made my search with Google and read all articles I can find on StackOverflow but I am still getting the error "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large" and can't quite seem to figure out how to resolve.

My app.config file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISyncService"
                 messageEncoding="Text"
                 textEncoding="utf-8"
                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 allowCookies="false"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                 openTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas
            maxDepth="2000000"
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport
              clientCredentialType="None"
              proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:51283/SyncService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISyncService" contract="SyncService.ISyncService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_ISyncService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: a) are you sure you're using the binding in the app.config, b) what exactly are you sending?

Comment: is the entity you are requesting self referencing or some other type of circle reference? Soap can't handle circle references.

Comment: @BugFinder: I have copied lines from App.config file. I am sending any kind of file.

Comment: @Rabban: I am not sure what you meant by "Self-referencing" but I am trying to send a file from my folder.

Comment: How big is the file and how do you send it?

Comment: @user3021830 You didnt answer the question, are you sure that the binding you use is from your app config?

Comment: @Rabban: File is approximately 3MB in size but I am planning to use for larger files as well. I am using it in a container class which holds FileInfo and string for file information and data.

Comment: @BugFinder : I don't understand what you mean, but I do not create any service relates code. Just coded as using(MyService.SvcClient = new ...) so I should be using the settings from the App.config file itself.

Comment: @mjwills Is there a httpRuntime attribute in app.config? I think I can only have it Web.Config.

Comment: I'm not sure that `FileInfo` works with wcf, but you can transfer your File as stream or byte array.

Comment: @Rabban It seeems that FileInfo works with WCF. If I try with a smaller file as 1KB it works. I think the problem is with WCF data size as the error message says. I have read a lot on it and applied suggestions but still can't get rid of it.